# Calculate all pairs of outer products between columns in matrix

Tags: matrices, loops

Imagine you have a matrix m of dimension MxN
What I'm trying to do is get a set of elements (of length N*(N-1)/2) of the diagonal elements (each of whose individual length would be M) of the outer product which is formed by every possible pair of columns within the matrix m

For instance, I would take outer product of  columns 1 and column 2 and extract that diagonal, then do the same with columns 1 and 3, columns 2 and 3,... etc)

Is there a quick way to do this without looping over every pair of columns (ie complexity O(N^2)

Currently how I have written it in R is:

```
for i in 1:ncols:
    for j in i:ncols:
        diag(outer(m[,i],m[,j]))
```

But obviously, this is painfully slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: The outer product of two vectors $x,y$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $x_i y_j$. So the diagonal elements are just the products $x_i y_i$. You can compute the diagonal elements directly.

Comment: Thank you, I just came to that realization too just now
Is there anyway to do the permutations quickly though?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "permutation". This word has a very specific meaning in mathematics, which might be different from what you intend.

Comment: The algorithm I outline takes $O(1)$ time per output, which is optimal. You cannot possibly do it any faster (up to a constant factor).

Comment: If you're asking how to program this in R, then the question becomes off-topic here.

Comment: Since the length of the output sequence is O(N^2) you can't do better than that as far as time complexity. You may still be able to shave off a bit of time someplace